# Reference env variables in a excel document for scanstate migration

Tags: windows, migration, deployment, usmt

I work for a company that is using a scanstate, loadstate type USMT migration script.
Their script references 3 variables: UserID, Source, and TargetComputer.

The script .cmd works just fine (which was created by other people).
But I was asked for help on tying the list of user, computer name, etc into the script for each user, which needs to run on its own.

We have a list of user ID's with their Computer Name, and New computer name,
But we need to run the script easily (with the variables tying in) without having to retype those variables manually every time.

The list is in an excel document. And the cmd us essentially a psexec onto the target (original, and new) computers.
The exec is running a batch file which scanstates, or loadstates.

There are two cmds, obviously one being the scan, and the other being the load.

Fairly simple if run with 1. But we are curious about doing this for thousands of users.

Please let me know..